# SQL Injection from a textbox

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I'm new to MS Access.

So, I wrote a SQL query(query name = qryEmployeeInfo) which shows employee information. The query outputs two columns. The employee ID(header name = employee_ID) and the corresponding employee address(header name = employee_address).

My Access form has a text box(text box name = txtEmployeeID) that I want the user to be able to enter the employee_ID into and have it output the corresponding employee_address into another text box (text box name = txtEmployeeAddress). I also want the employee_address to be in the format of a string variable so I can perform other VBA checks on it later(for example - if LIKE "California" THEN...something).

I want to write what (I think) is called an injection SQL query so that I can pull the address data from the query for that specific employee_ID. I believe the format should look like this:

```
Dim rs As Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("select employee_address from qryEmployeeInfo where employee_ID = "' & txtEmployeeID & "'", dbOpenDynaset)
```

Do I have this written correctly?

If so, then how do I get that output into a string variable format(variable name = strEmployeeAddress)?

After I get the employee address into a string variable format I want to simply use txtEmployeeAddress.value = strEmployeeAddress to populate the employee address text box. Again, I also want the employee_address to be in the format of a string variable so I can perform other VBA checks on it later(for example - if LIKE "California" THEN...something).

Any help you could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why would you need to retrieve employee_ID if you already employee_ID in textbox?

Comment: I initially wrote my query wrong :( it should be employee_address. I just fixed it in my post...it should make more sense now.

Comment: "SQL injection" is a term used for when users intentionally enter malformed values into text inputs in an attempt to either damage the database or gain access to privileged data without proper access.  This only works when building queries by concatenating search values into the SQL, and it considered an insecure way to architect a query.  Ideally you use a *parameterized* query, which protects you against SQL injection.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If employee_ID is a number field, remove apostrophe delimiters.

If employee_ID is a text field, move first apostrophe so it is within quote marks.
`"select employee_address from qryEmployeeInfo where employee_ID = '" & txtEmployeeID & "'"`

Then `txtEmployeeAddress = rs!employee_address`

However, instead of opening a recordset object, could just use DLookup.
`txtEmployeeAddress = DLookup("employee_address", "qryEmployeeInfo", "employee_ID =" & txtEmployeeID)`

Or even better, eliminate the VBA. The DLookup() expression can be in textbox ControlSource property, just precede with = sign.

However, domain aggregate functions can perform slowly. So instead of textbox, use a combobox for selecting employee. Include employee information in combobox RowSource. Expression in textbox references column of combobox: `=combobox.Column(1)`. Issue is combobox has limit on how many characters can be pulled into column so if field is memo (long text) type, this approach is not feasible and should use DLookup.

The address will be available in textbox for use as long as this form is open. If you want the address to be available to other procedures even after form is closed, then need to set a global or public variable. Such variable must be declared in a module header to make it available to multiple procedures. TempVars are another way to hold values for future use. I have never used them.

Comment: The employee ID is actually a composite of letters and numbers. 

Regarding the recordset object, I was really hoping to use this example to better understand how to use recordset objects since I'm a noob and want to better understand how they work. But I do like your DLookup solution.

Comment: Well, now you learned about recordsets and some other stuff. Edited my answer with more info. If it resolved issue, please mark as accepted.

Comment: Just curious, is my original code correct and is there a way for that to output a string variable as it stands?

Comment: You declare a variable then set that variable basically same way as textbox value was set. Re-read last paragraph in my answer.

Comment: Just curious, how does recordset and DLookup handle the possibility of one employee_ID having two employee_address outputs(for example, one specific employee shows an address on the east coast and an address on west coast)?..would it result in an error?

Comment: The recordset will pull both records but the variable will only be set to the first. The DLookup will pull one value but which cannot be known for sure.